# How do I remove the header in the df command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash command that will sort all volumes by the amount of data they have used and tried using

```
df | awk '{print $1 | "sort -r -k3 -n"}'
```

Output:

```
map
devfs
Filesystem
/dev/disk1s5
/dev/disk1s2
/dev/disk1s1
```

But this also shows the header called Filesystem.
How do I remove that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `tail -n +2` to remove the first line in `df` (or any other command) output:

```bash
df | tail -n +2 | sort -r -k3 -n
```

Explanation: `tail -n +N` outputs starting with line `N`.

In a more general case, in order to remove the first lines of any output, you can use the `tail -n +N` to start with line `N`:

```bash
command | tail -n +2 | other_command
```

Answer (score 3):

Skip the first line, like this:

```
df | awk 'NR>1 {print $1 | "sort -r -k3 -n"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I normally use one of these options, if I have no reason to use awk:

```
df | sed 1d
```

The *1d* option to sed says delete the first line, then print everything else.

```
df | tail -n+2
```

the *-n+2* option to tail say start looking at line 2 and print everything until End-of-Input.

I suspect *sed* is faster than *awk* or *tail*, but I can't prove it.

**EDIT**
If you want to use awk, this will print every line except the first:

```
df | awk '{if (FNR>1) print}'
```

*FNR* is the *F*ile *R*ecord *N*umber. It is the line number of the input. If it is greater than 1, *print* the input line.

Answer (score 2):

Count the lines from the output of `df` with `wc` and then substract one line to output a headerless `df` with `tail` ...

```
LINES=$(df|wc -l)
LINES=$((${LINES}-1))
df | tail -n ${LINES}
```

OK - I see oneliner - Here is mine ...

```
DF_HEADERLESS=$(LINES=$(df|wc -l); LINES=$((${LINES}-1));df | tail -n ${LINES})
```

And for formated output lets printf loop over it...

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" ${DF_HEADERLESS} | awk '{print $1 | "sort -r -k3 -n"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help with GNU df and GNU sort:

```
df -P | awk 'NR>1{$1=$1; print}' | sort -r -k3 -n | awk '{print $1}'
```

With GNU df and GNU awk:

```
df -P | awk 'NR>1{array[$3]=$1} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc"; for(i in array){print array[i]}}'
```

---

Documentation: [8.1.6 Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning)

Answer (score 1):

Removing something from a command output can be done very simply, using `grep -v`, so in your case:

```
df | grep -v "Filesystem" | ...
```

(You can do your `awk` at the `...`)

When you're not sure about caps, small caps, you might add `-i`:

```
df | grep -i -v "FiLeSyStEm" | ...
```

(The switching caps/small caps are meant as a clarification joke :-) )